# Does it make sense to deploy a WAR with a webapp to Maven central repository?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2, maven, jetty

Does it make sense to do that? If yes, where can I find an example of doing that with a simple "Hello World from Web"? Do people run webapps with Jetty when they execute it from Maven? I imagine tomcat is too heavy for that.

Any help will be appreciated! Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deploy `.war` files to our internal Archiva Maven repository so that I can pull them down to assembly things like RPMS without having to hand copy files around, same with building assemblies. It also is useful when the `.war` is something like a service that is generic and may be included in multiple other web app compliations.

That said, Central is probably **NOT** the place to be deploying `.war` files to.

Answer (score 1):

Imo, the central repository should contain libraries not applications. It's just for resolving dependencies and maven plugins.

Comment: Deploying to the central repository can't be done automatically btw - it is moderated.

Comment: Actually it can be done automatically, I deploy my open source libraries to Sonatype and they push to Central automatically if you meet their requirements, completely automated from Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Central is not the right place for this, you should be deploying applications to a local respository. Nexus is fairly easy to setup and is a good place to start: http://nexus.sonatype.org/

There are other alternatives such as Artifacotry http://www.jfrog.com/products.php

Jetty is a great way to make sure things are up and running but during development Tomcat with your IDE's server plugin is just as lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

We have used it once, for a very special case though. We deploy one of our servlet as part of a third-party web application delivered as a .war file. The third-party war in this case is deployed to the central repository. We use it as dependency in our servlet project, download it during the build process, replace the existing WEB-INF/web.xml with our own customized version (that has our servlet declaration), add the servlet class to the war and ship it. 
  [Jackrabbit Standalone](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-standalone.html) is an example of an web-app within Jetty. Yes, jetty is lightweight. The source code for Jettification of  the standalone can be downloaded from the Jackrabbit's [public repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/tags/2.3.0/jackrabbit-standalone/) if you want to give it a try. Its mavenized and they build it as [bundle](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) so that you can just run the web-app within jetty  out of the box.