# Standalone jar and maven central

Tags: java, jar, maven-central

I have a standalone jar (standalone = executable via `java -jar ...`), which can be downloaded manually from website. I was wondering if there is any use case, for which it would make sense to push it to Maven Central?

Comment: No. Maven central is for libraries usable by other applications. Not for applications themselves.

Comment: Perhaps, You only need deploy your "standalone Jar" in your own binary repository, as artifactory or nexus.

Comment: Can't think of any. This has been previously discussed in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679143/does-it-make-sense-to-deploy-a-war-with-a-webapp-to-maven-central-repository) in the context of .wars, and I think the same reasoning applies. There are a few example projects where this has been done (at least for wars), but I'm not really convinced of the reasoning. Like the link mentions, for *local* repository managers however this might make a lot of sense.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679143/does-it-make-sense-to-deploy-a-war-with-a-webapp-to-maven-central-repository for reasons above.

Answer (score -1):

You could do that by your own nexus/archiva/artifactory application as server that is public visible.
Then you need to configure your maven's settings.xml for that server and make `mvn deploy` so your standalone.jar can be deployed remotely to this server as snapshot or release version.

Please refer to:

http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/

http://archiva.apache.org/

http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP asked if there is some situation where it would make sense to push it to maven central.